# Pass extra field to serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model for price tags, let's say it contains only price. I want to pass image of the price tag to serializer then call method for text recognition inside serializer and pass recognized price to model. But I don't need image field in my model. How do I add extra field to serializer which doesn't relate to model?
This is the serializer:

```
class CartProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = ImageField()

    class Meta:
        model = CartProduct
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        data = validated_data['image']
        path = default_storage.save('tmp/somename.jpg', ContentFile(data.read()))
        detect_pricetag(path)
        return super().create(validated_data)
```

But I got this error:

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `image` on serializer `CartProductSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `CartProduct` instance.
Original exception text was: 'CartProduct' object has no attribute 'image'.
```

Deleting 'image' object from `validated_data` doesn't help.
Is there any chance to use DRF serializer field for POST request which is not in the model?

Comment: instead of `data = validate_date['image']`, do `data = validated_data.pop('image')`. I don't know how you tried to "delete 'image' from `validated_data`" as you said, but it should work.

Comment: ah, I see the error is on serialising, not de-serializing. Can you show the full stack trace, this isn't happening in the `create()` method I believe.

Comment: set `write_only=True` on your `ImageField()` and also `pop('image')` in your create method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to use the field when serializing a `CartProduct`, so it should be write-only.

```
image = ImageField(write_only=True)
```

Also you don't want it to be used to instantiate a `CartProduct`, so you should remove it from the validated data before saving:

```
data = validated_data.pop('image', None)
...
return super().create(validated_data)
```

Comment: Thank you. `write_only` is the key

Comment: I think it should be clearer on the documentation. You saved my day, thanks!